# An image place horizontally next to a list

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="row">
      <ul class='list-group .col-md-6'> <li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li>  </ul>
      <div>
        <img class=".col-md-6" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7613/16147502573_613d5f6b23.jpg" />
      </div>
</div>
```

Pretend the list elements are placeholders.
What I want to do is have a list on the left half of the window, and an image on the right half of the window (preferably centered vertically with the list, if any of you guys know how to do that as well)
I thought using bootstrap grid system would work but I'm a newbie at bootstrap and it is not resulting in a side by side depiction, but the image appears under the list. And yes, I already have bootstrap imported and fetched. And no, removing the div around the image didnt make a difference.

Also if bootstrap isn't the best way to do this, I'm okay with accepting plain CSS answers.

Comment: apply `float:left` to `ul` and `float:right` for `img`

Comment: it worked, thanks @MerajKhan

Comment: welcome. if it is useful accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply `float:left` to ul and `float:right` to the `img`.

Comment: You wont need any CSS, Bootstrap has the classes `float-left` and `float-right`.